# Ignore special characters when reading PDFs

Tags: python, unicode

I am using `pdfplumber` to scrape PDF text. I am then using `write` (from package `string`) to write this to a text file. This was working pretty well until the pdfs started adding special characters (such as ↓ ). Now when I go to write it to a text file I get a unicode error. Is there anyway to ignore this special character and write the rest of the text?

**Code:**

```
dataFile = open('AgW1.txt','w')
for eachitem in aList:
    dataFile.write(str(eachitem)+'\n')
```

**Traceback**:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-13532302c2d5> in <module>
      1 for eachitem in aList:
----> 2     dataFile.write(str(eachitem)+'\n')

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2193' in position 63: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You should add code fences (``` ```) between your codes so it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `utf-8` encoding to your file open, i.e. `dataFile = open('AgW1.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')`.